# Bank statement for UK visa if I am unemployed

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

Can I use the bank statement of my sponsor i.e. my aunt for UK standard visitor visa? I am currently unemployed so do I still need to create a bank account and she put money in it for me?

This aunt has been my guardian since I was 14, I am now 27. My situation is that I am awaiting a job by July and I wish to pass PLAB1 by June, 2017.

Comment: We have numerous questions on this site about refusals for people who want to sit through a PLAB exam: https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=plab+%5Bvisa-refusal%5D. Avoid applying for a visa with sub-par documents unless absolutely necessary. Note that PLAB1 can be taken in Egypt instead: http://www.britishcouncil.org.eg/en/exam/medical/plab

Comment: @JonathanReez spot on with the Egypt link!

Comment: Please read http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab in its entirity.

Comment: What you propose to do is to have your aunt park funds in your account. Bad strategy. Does it not betray a willingness to deceive them? They will think so. Search this site for 'funds parking'.

Comment: @GayotFow can we close this as a dupe of "Should I submit bank statements..."?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They want to see *your* bank statements to gauge your conditions of living, and the likelihood that you will return home after the visit. Not having a bank account might appear to be *unusual* for people who want to visit the UK for a professional examination.

It is normal that younger people get money from older relatives. If so, the visa officials want to know if if the money comes from legal sources, if the amount is reasonable for your relative, and if it is truly a gift to you. So that part of your aunt's finances need to be explained.

So the best case is **having had** a bank account for some time prior to the appication. Deposits should exceed withdrawals and they need to come at a regular pattern. Creating an account now and depositing large amounts of money does not help.